# To which class of calligraphic fonts does the following `\mathcal{K}` correspond to?

Tags: fonts, packages, calligraphy

In one of the research articles I was reading I noticed this special calligraphic `\mathcal{K}`

[image]

What class of fonts (package) is this font generated from?

Comment: Looks like Euler Script to me. Try `\usepackage{eulervm}` and `\mathcal{K}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm that this is the Euler calligraphic font. You can also get it with the package [`mathalpha`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=euler]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\(\mathcal{K}\)
\end{document}
```